# Using XML Files to move SQL Data between servers

Tags: sql-server, xml, batch-file

I have to move data from one SQL database to an exact copy on another server. I am aware of the alternative methods of doing this which may be easier, but due to this not being my decision, my only way of doing this is exporting the data from the table into an XML file, before importing on the other server.

I am currently developing and testing this solution with the most complex table, which also contains an extremely large XML field. This exports to file, using the following command in a .bat file.

```
ECHO OFF

sqlcmd -h-1 -y0 -k1 -S [server name] -d [database name] -E -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT TOP 3 * FROM t_section FOR XML PATH" -o TestSectionResult.xml
```

However when I look at the export file it has reformatted slightly, adding additional line breaks, which when I try to copy and paste into the import function makes it invalid. Is there anything I can do to get around this problem and have the XML ***exactly*** as it comes out of the query, as it works perfectly when copied directly from SSMS.

This leads into my second problem, which is that the stored procedure I have to import the XML works perfectly well when the XML is pasted in its correct format, but I need to be able to import it from a file, which should be provided in the .bat file command.

I know that OPENROWSET seems to be the standard way to read from files, but I need it to be done from the .bat file. What would be the correct way to insert this value in a sqlcmd?

Right now I have this as my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE usp_xml_to_section 

    @inputXML XML

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --TRUNCATE TABLE t_section;

    --INSERT INTO t_section
    SELECT 
        xmlRows.value('Id[1]', 'int') AS Id, 
        xmlRows.value('work_item_id[1]', 'int') AS work_item_id,
        xmlRows.value('section_type_id[1]', 'int') AS section_type_id,
        xmlRows.value('section_state_id[1]', 'int') AS section_state_id,
        xmlRows.query('section_xml[1]/*') AS section_xml,
        xmlRows.value('created_date[1]', 'datetime') AS created_date,
        xmlRows.value('created_by[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') AS created_by,
        xmlRows.value('updated_date[1]', 'datetime') AS updated_date,
        xmlRows.value('updated_by[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') AS updated_by,
        xmlRows.value('active[1]', 'bit') AS active
    FROM @inputXML.nodes('/row') AS XTbl(xmlRows)

END
GO
```

I don't know how to pass an xml file into this and get the expected outcome. If anybody could provide any help or links to allow me to do that it would be much appreciated.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you undo the formatting within your batch file before sending it on to the stored proc?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but I don't know how to read the data from the file into the batch file query anyway at the moment.  I'm also trying to escape the XML field in the table at the moment as it contains ' characters. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now changed tactics and instead used a c# Windows Console application to do this and it was far simpler and more effective.